# Evaluation of the loss function

Tags: keras, r

Why the three evaluations of the loss in the following code do not agree?

```
library(keras)

# data
X <- cbind(1, sin(2*i*pi*(1:1000)/365), cos(2*i*pi*(1:1000)/365))
mu <- 1 + .1*X[,2] + .5*X[,3]
sigma <- exp(1 + .1*X[,2] + .5*X[,3])
y <- rnorm(1000,mu,sigma)

custom_loss <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
  mu <- y_pred[,1]
  sigma <- exp(y_pred[,2])
  return(-tf$reduce_mean(tfprobability::tfd_normal(mu, sigma)$log_prob(c(y_true))))
}

# keras model -------------------------------------------------------------
input_fou <- layer_input(shape = 3)
output <- input_fou %>% layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "linear", use_bias = F)
model <- keras_model(inputs = input_fou, outputs = output)

# Compile the model with your custom loss function
model %>% compile(optimizer = optimizer_sgd(), loss = custom_loss,  metrics = custom_loss)

# loss and metric (both supposed to be the same?)
evaluate(model, X, y)

# loss again (this time it gives the correct answer)
custom_loss(y, predict(model, X))

# true loss
mean(dnorm(y, pred[,1], exp(pred[,2]), log=T))
```

Comment: In a more elaborate case I am working on (involving the gamma distribution), when I initialize my model with the optimal weights, I get that my model converges to an intercept model. (This might happen in the above example too, idk). I suspect that the problem might come from there.